# Show twitter timeline or tweets related to a particular hashtag in custom table view using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know using Fabric we can get the tweets on a users timeline or related to a particular hashtag.

```
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", APIClient: client)
```

But these tweets can be shown in TWTRTimelineViewController. Is there a way to show the tweets in custom table view? Moreover how do we know if the tweets have been loaded?